Trying to update state but initial value is still logged in React
I'm trying to update state of a variable showResultModal to show a modal (popup) after a user has deleted their comment but showResultModal never gets updated. I'm using the useState hook to update the state but because of it's asynchronous nature the initial value is used so the modal never shows up. I read other solutions suggesting using the useEffect hook but still no luck.
DeleteComment.tsx:
import { deleteComment } from "../../utils/api";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { MessageModal, ResultModal } from "../Modal";

type Comment = {
  author: string;
  comment_id: string;
};
type Props = {
  comment: Comment;
  onDelete: Function;
};

export default function DeleteCommentById({ comment, onDelete }: Props) {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [showResultModal, setShowResultModal] = useState(false);
  console.log(showResultModal)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showResultModal) {
      console.log('changed')
    } else {
      console.log('no change')
    }
  },[showResultModal])

  const handleDelete = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("user") === comment.author) {
        setShowModal(false);
        onDelete(comment.comment_id);
        await deleteComment(comment.comment_id);
        setShowResultModal(true)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setShowResultModal(true)
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MessageModal
        show={showModal}
        onClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
        title="Confirm"
        message="Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"
        onConfirm={handleDelete}
      />
    <ResultModal show={showResultModal} onClose={() => setShowResultModal(false)} title={'resultTitle'} message={'resultMessage'} />
      <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
}

Modal.tsx:
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import React from "react";

type MessageModalProps = {
  show: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  title: string;
  message: string;
  onConfirm: any;
};

export const MessageModal: React.FC<MessageModalProps> = ({ show, onClose, title, message, onConfirm }) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={show}>
      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{message}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={onConfirm}>Confirm</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

type ResultModalProps = {
  show: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  title: string;
  message: string;
};

export const ResultModal: React.FC<ResultModalProps> = ({ show, onClose, title, message }) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={show}>
      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{message}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onClose}>
          Close
        </button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

api function:
export const deleteComment = (id: string) => {
  return axios
    .delete(
      `localhost/api/comments/${id}`
    )
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Deleted comment ${id}`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    });
};


update state of a variable which variable?  the modal never shows up which modal?  I think you mean that setShowResultModal(true) within the try block of handleDelete is not causing the result modal to show up, can you clarify?

The showResultModal variable is the one to be updated and the Result modal is the one I'm having issues with

@AhmedMohamed Confirm that the code in handleDelete actually runs  considering you have an if statement

@Hilory yes the code in  handleDelete runs but the setShowResultModal(true) line doesn't

Your question is not clear. But I suggest to check that your comment.author check returns true inside of handleDelete function first. And after that check all other lines if it will not help. Good luck.

It is returning true because the way the component is set up is to render a delete button ONLY on a comment that belongs to the logged in user. This is fine, my concern is my Result modal not showing up after a user has successfully deleted their comment
